# To change Azure PostgreSQL Managed Database default Timezone?

Tags: postgresql, azure, timezone

I have gone through many posts,but I cloudn't get a clear view on changing **Azure PostgreSQL Managed database** timezone from default **'UTC'** to other timezones.

So is it possible to change Azure PostgreSQL Managed database timezone from **'UTC'** ? 
If so, can you please suggest a way.

Thanks, xlr8

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: While this might not solve your issue, one option is to convert the timezone on the client to their local time.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands now there is no way to change the default timezone. It's a feature thats been backlogged [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/18739267-need-the-ability-to-set-a-time-zone-per-azure-sql).

You can convert time based on timezone using [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '03/29/2015 01:01:00')   
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';  
--2015-03-29 01:01:00.000 +01:00  

--Time between 02:00 and 03:00 is converted as +01!  
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '03/29/2015 02:01:00')   
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';  
--2015-03-29 02:01:00.000 +01:00  

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '03/29/2015 03:01:00')   
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';  
--2015-03-29 03:01:00.000 +02:00
```

Comment: Your approach is fine, but you've linked to MS SQL Server's version of `AT TIME ZONE` instead of PostgreSQL's which is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT).  Also, the time zones you gave are Windows time zone Ids.  They should be [IANA TZDB time zone IDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to work with PostgreSQL.